# How to enable the Migrations in My MVC5 Project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Following Error i get it,
Migrations is enabled for context 'ApplicationDbContext' but the database does not exist or contains no mapped tables. Use Migrations to create the database and its tables, for example by running the 'Update-Database' command from the Package Manager Consol

Comment: PM> Update-Database it not working to me.Please send me migration enable process step by step.

Comment: Hi @Raja, I'm suppose you have your own dataContext other than `ApplicationDbContext`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to perform this commands in Package Manager Consol

```
Enable-Migrations

Add-Migration "Initial"

Update-Database
```

There you will have a database with migrations based on your models classes

Comment: Hi,
          The Same thing I do it in my project but I got this error,
"Migrations is enabled for context 'ApplicationDbContext' but the database does not exist or contains no mapped tables. Use Migrations to create the database and its tables, for example by running the 'Update-Database' command from the Package Manager Console"

Comment: Do you set the connection string? It is valid? Is there physicly database fil(.mdf) in your project (default in APP_DATA)?